# Conditional Formatting of Labels of Functions in a Grid of Plots

Tags: plotting, labeling, grid-layouts

I have a panel of graphs where each graph shows the same functions but at different values.

I want to label them with `Labeled`, however, as the label is quite spacious, it does not fit if I use a uniform place to fit it.

Consider the following reduced example:

First, I create some data:

```
function1[x_] := u x^2
function2[x_] := v Sin[x]

fObs = Flatten[
   Table[{function1[x], function2[x], u, v}, {u, {4, 5, 6}}, {v, { 1, 2, 3}}], 1];
```

and the Plot:

```
Grid@Partition[Map[Show[

 Plot[Labeled[
   #[[1]],
   "f1- first", {Scaled [2/3], Left}
    ], {x, 0, 1}, 
  PlotLabel -> 
   Style[("u= " <> ToString[#[[3]]] <> ", v=" <> 
      ToString[#[[4]] ] ), Black]],

 Plot[Labeled[
   #[[2]],
   "f2- second", {.9, Below}
    ], {x, 0, 1}

  ]

 ] &, fObs]
           , UpTo[2]]
```

The result looks as follows: 
[image]

As an example, I want to have the labels on the right for the first three rows and on the left for the following row.

So, I created `Piecewise` functions in the hope change the labeling for some values in the grid. However, the `Labeled` command of the `Piecewise` function, where the function is outside the relevant area still produces a label. It is placed on the axis (highlighted).

```
 Grid@Partition[Map[Show[

 Plot[Labeled[
   #[[1]],
   "f1- first", {Scaled [2/3], Left}
    ], {x, 0, 1}, 
  PlotLabel -> 
   Style[("u= " <> ToString[#[[3]]] <> ", v=" <> 
      ToString[#[[4]] ] ), Black]
  ],

 Plot[Labeled[Piecewise[{{
      #[[2]], #[[3]] <= 5}, {-100, #[[3]] > 5}}],
   "f2- second", {.1, Above}
    ], {x, 0, 1}
  ],
 Plot[Labeled[Piecewise[{{
      #[[2]], #[[3]] > 5}, {-10, #[[3]] > 5}}],
   "f2- second", {.9, Below}
    ], {x, 0, 1}
  ]


 ] &, fObs]
   , UpTo[2]]
```

[image]

Is there a better clean way to create conditional labeling in that context?

Also, I am wondering why the double labeling does not occur in the last three plots.

Comment: Not an answer, but a plot is missing, there should be 9. Change the `2` argument to `UpTo[2]` so `Partition` includes it.

Comment: Thanks @RohitNamjoshi, I added that. Somehow missed it...